# Converting date column in sqlite, can't query against it

Tags: sql, database, date, sqlite

I'm importing .csv files into an SQLite database. I am attempting to query against one of the tables. I think it is getting hung up on dates, which are in *MM/DD/YYYY* format. Not all months and days are two digits either.

I've tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> 
WHERE 'account' = <account_number> 
and 'date' between '1900-01-01' and '2013-03-03'
```

I've also tried:

```
select * from <table> 
where 'account' = <account_number> 
and 'date' > '1901-01-01' and 'date' < '2013-03-03'
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: *I think it is getting hung up on dates* and *it doesn't work*: These are very vague descriptions. Please be as specific as possible (error message, which query, have you tried to limit the records being queried to pinpoint the offending record, ... etc).

Comment: @It isn't returning anything. It should return records, but it returns nothing when I query the dates which are in a *MM/DD/YYYY* format. If I remove the date columns it returns data.

There are no error messages.

Comment: What is the data type of the date column? Can you give the CREATE TABLE statement for it?

Comment: `PRAGMA table_info()` returns `date,date,1,,0` The table is created through the `.import` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Names of columns should not be put in single quotes.

```
select   * 
from     mytable 
where    account = <account_number> 
and      date between '1901-01-01' and '2013-03-02'
```

Note also the use of `between`.

As to the date format: of course you should make sure to insert records with the correct YYYY-MM-DD format.

If you cannot control the format of the imported data, then I suggest to apply a correction after the import:

```
update mytable
set date = substr(date, -4) || '-' ||  
           substr('0' || substr(date, 1, instr(date, '/')-1), -2) || '-' ||
           substr('0' || substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1, 
                         length(date)-5-instr(date, '/')), -2)
where date like '_%/_%/____';
```

This will find any dates in the M/D/YYYY format (with one or two digits for day and month), and will move the year part to the beginning to get the YYYY-MM-DD format. If you know for sure the original format was MM/DD/YYYY (and not DD/MM/YYYY), then this should correct all those dates.

Check out [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8d9e7/1) that applies this fix to a few sample dates.

Comment: The date format is what I'm having trouble with. I'm importing into the the database with `.import` and the original data has it in that format. Is there a way to reliable convert it?

Comment: You could look into creating a trigger on your table which will correct dates that have a wrong format.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a corrective `update` statement which aims to convert dates into the right format.